# Referencing another class variable in Java

Tags: java, android, class, variables

I thought I had this figured out, but I obviously don't.

In an Android App I'm making a spinner will change it's contents based on a previous spinner's selection. The listener works and the second spinner is changing, however there is a third spinner that is not getting its contents.

What I would like to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
if (spinner1.selection == "Acura") {
spinner2 = "Acura";
}
```

The string-arrays that I'm calling are integers in the `R.java` file so for Acura it would be: `R.array.Acura`

So my question would be:

How can I call the integer `R.array.*` dynamically based on a string.

I hope my question makes sense.

Cheers

Comment: Also, use `.equals` instead of `==` on strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method on your activity to look up the resource ID.

For example:

```
spinner2 = "Acura";
int arrayResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(spinner2, "array", getPackageName());
```

Comment: You, my friend, are an absolute legend.
Thank you very much!